# Javascript - Compare array of objects and sum coincident values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects:

```
arr=[
     {a: 1,b: 0,x: 100},
     {a: 0,b: 0,x: 100},
     {a: 1,b: 1,x: 100},
     {a: 1,b: 0,x: 200},
     {a: 1,b: 1,x: 200},
     ....
]
```

Now, what I need to do is to compare "x" values and if they coincide, tranfer summed "a" and "b" values in another array. For example:

arr2=[{a=2,b=1,x=100},{a=2,b=1,x=200}....]

Second thing to do, is to count how many objects are been joined with the same "x" value. For example in the first "arr2" object are joined 3 "arr" objects and in the second "arr2" object are joined 2 "arr" objects  and so on.

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Are you aware that your data has syntax errors?

Comment: yes... homework :) hum... is embarassing that I don't know where to start, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't seem to make sense. First of all, the word "coincident" doesn't have a technical definition that I'm aware of. Can you be more clear about what you mean?

Secondly its not clear what your expected results are. Perhaps what I would do if I was you would be to start with some simple example inputs and then come up with what you would expect the corresponding output to be, then use a unit testing tool to develop the code to do what you want.

For example, I have to guess what you are wanting but it might look like this (in javascript) using the libraries chai and mocha:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'

function doWork(input) {
  // code goes here
}

const tests = [
  {
    name: 'Same x values coalesce',
    data: [
      {a=1,b=0,x=100},
      {a=0,b=0,x=100}
    ],
    expected: {
      100: [1, 0]
    }
  } 
]
describe('work', () => {
  tests.forEach(test => {
    it(t.name, () => {
      const result = doWork(test.data)
      expect(result).to.deep.equal(test.expected)
    })
  })
})
```

This technique may help you come to to an answer on your own.

Try to be a little more precise with your terms and give an example of what you are expecting to get as output.

Answer (score 0):

Array reduce and map are fun methods. Object.keys() will give you an array of keys and that lets you do more array reducing and mapping. Fun times.

```js
    let arr = [
        { a: 1, b: 0, x: 100 },
        { a: 0, b: 0, x: 100 },
        { a: 1, b: 1, x: 100 },
        { a: 1, b: 0, x: 200 },
        { a: 1, b: 1, x: 200 }
    ];

    let lists = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        let list = prev[curr.x] || [];
        list.push(curr);
        prev[curr.x] = list;
        return prev;
    }, {});

    console.log(lists);

    let flat = Object.keys(lists).reduce((prev, curr) => {
        prev.push(
            lists[curr].reduce(
                (prev, curr) => {
                    prev.a += curr.a;
                    prev.b += curr.b;
                    prev.x = curr.x;
                    return prev;
                },
                { a: 0, b: 0 }
            )
        );

        return prev;
    }, []);

    console.log(flat);

    Object.keys(lists).forEach(el => console.log(el + ': ' + lists[el].length));
```